# Changing node color OGDF Library

Tags: c++, ogdf

I am trying to change the node color using the following code but getting Segmentation fault.

I am using the latest OGDF snapshot.

```
Graph G;
GraphAttributes GA(G, GraphAttributes::nodeGraphics |   
         GraphAttributes::edgeGraphics );

node left = G.newNode();
GA.strokeColor (left) = Color("red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `GraphAttributes::nodeGraphics` only enables coordinates and shapes of the node but not its color. For the stroke and fill styling, you need to enable `GraphAttributes::nodeStyle` in the constructor:

```
Graph G;
GraphAttributes GA(G,
        GraphAttributes::nodeGraphics |   
        GraphAttributes::nodeStyle |      // <-- Enables node stroke and filling
        GraphAttributes::edgeGraphics );

node left = G.newNode();
GA.strokeColor(left) = Color("red");
```

For a mapping of attributes you can use and the enum values you need to enable in the constructor (or later), see the [documentation of the enumeration](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf-dev/classogdf_1_1_graph_attributes.html#a2d749f26af4746b8f874c47fcc2f1125).